# How to extract contents from a .ipa file (2018)

Tags: ios, zip, unzip, ipa

Most information found online stated that this could be done with `unzip(1)`, but unfortunately it is not the case anymore, .ipa file format has changed, with `unzip -v xyz.ipa`:

```
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 09-18-2018 15:38 00000000  META-INF/
     379  Unk:099     367   3% 09-19-2018 08:44 bf0c5de5  META-INF/com.apple.ZipMetadata.plist
      23  Stored       23   0% 09-19-2018 08:44 132aa79c  META-INF/com.apple.FixedZipMetadata.bin
       0  Stored        0   0% 09-18-2018 15:36 00000000  Payload/
       0  Stored        0   0% 09-19-2018 23:44 00000000  Payload/xyz.app/
       0  Stored        0   0% 09-18-2018 15:36 00000000  Payload/xyz.app/_CodeSignature/
  358128  Unk:099   84505  76% 09-19-2018 23:44 7f51c7bf  Payload/xyz.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
   10131  Unk:099    2190  78% 09-18-2018 15:36 90a256db  Payload/xyz.app/Info.plist
```

for those files with compress method `099`, can not be extracted, I guess they are encrypted or encoded with a specifically designed compress method.

the .ipa file is grabbed from app store, you could obtain it via [filebin](https://filebin.net/r96lxj7tg1vvd85y/2.ipa?t=86x3xpt9).

How could I get the .ipa file extracted?

Comment: change the .ipa extension to zip first then unzip it. After unzipping you can find .aap file to see the content right click on the .app file and select show package content.

Comment: @vivekDas extension is meaningless to unzip.

Comment: just change the .ipa to .zip and double click on this it will unzipped.

Comment: @vivekDas if simple trick like this works why do I bother to ask on SO :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple uses LZFSE compression for ipa packages. You'll need unzip with LZFSE support. For example https://github.com/sskaje/unzip-lzfse .

Answer (score 30):

Yes i have opened plenty app by changing a .ipa to a .zip it does work then you have to find the payload folder then right click it and choose "Show Package Contents" then you are in the app

Answer (score 9):

## Exporting ipa packages in 2021

1. Go to the Mac App Store, search for Apple Configurator 2 and download and install it.
2. Connect your iPhone to your Mac, click on Apple Configurator 2, click on the top menu bar ->**Account**->**Login**, and enter your iPhone login Apple ID.
3. Click **Action**->**Add**->**Apps...** and select the app to download.*(Before this step, you must have entered the details window of your iphone and make sure you have the app installed in your iPhone App Store.)*
4. When the download is complete, a prompt will appear, do not click the button on the pop-up box at this time.
5. Open Finder, Use the shortcut command+shift+G and type the following path.

```
~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Assets/TemporaryItems/MobileApps/
```

You can see the package we need, make sure to copy the installation package out at this time. This is the package we need to install.

6. Then change the .ipa file extension to .zip, and double-click to unzip it.

Answer (score 4):

just open with "archive Utility.app" which can be downloaded from the app store

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract it on **Windows**, you can just change the extension to **.zip** then extract it normally.

example: app.ipa >> app.ipa.zip then extract it normally

Comment: thanks i did extract my .ipa after rename into .zip on macos

Answer (score 1):

Another free option is [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com) – just drag the .ipa file onto its icon and it will be unzipped, without having to change its extension.